# MySQL SELECT, LEFT JOIN and COUNT() in one query returns error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got stuck with fairly plain query!

Briefly, I have created a search (filter) panel and now I'm adding pagination to it.

I'm having a problem in returning the number of rows that is in current query, mostly dependent on dynamically changing `$detailed_search_query` variable.

I need to make the following work, with adding COUNT() to it properly, so the new row total would contain the overall number of `unique_id`'s.

**Current SQL:**

```
$sql = $db->prepare( "
              SELECT
                individuals.individual_id,
                individuals.unique_id,
                individuals.fullname,
                individuals.day_of_birth,
                TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,individuals.day_of_birth,CURDATE()) AS age,
                individuals.gender,
                individuals.record_timestamp,
                individuals.active,
                individuals.deleted,
                individuals_dynamics.weight,
                individuals_dynamics.degree,
                individuals_dynamics.trainer_name
              FROM
                individuals as individuals
              LEFT JOIN
                individuals_dynamics AS individuals_dynamics ON individuals.unique_id = individuals_dynamics.individual_id
              WHERE
                $detailed_search_query $display recognized = 'yes' 
              GROUP BY
                individuals.record_timestamp
              ORDER BY $by $how
              LIMIT " . $limit);
```

If I add COUNT() to it, I have PDO error saying `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`.

This is how my new query ( just beginning, rest is the same ) looks like, that returns error above:

```
$sql = $db->prepare( "
                  SELECT
                    COUNT(individuals.unique_id),
                    individuals.individual_id,
                    individuals.unique_id,
                    individuals.fullname,
                    individuals.day_of_birth,
```

What am I missing here?

#### **EDIT 1:**

The example of how I use COUNT() results in plain pre-query that works:

```
 $sql              = $db->prepare("SELECT count(unique_id) FROM individuals");
 $sql->execute();
 $total            = $sql->fetchColumn();
 $pagination       = new Pagination($paginate_number);
 $limit            = $pagination->getLimit($total);
```

#### **EDIT 2:**

Yes, right, when I add an alias same error returns, example:

```
$sql = $db->prepare( "
                  SELECT
                    COUNT(individuals.unique_id) as total,
                    individuals.individual_id,
```

#### **EDIT 3:**

It's my bad about the last EDIT, if you add alias, like as total, then query works BUT it only COUNTS current row and returns 1 but I need total row count, example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [individual_id] => 51
            [1] => 51
            [unique_id] => f598edae
            [2] => f598edae
```

#### **EDIT 4:**

When the PHP variables are replaced then I have something like this in WHERE clause:

```
                  WHERE
                    individuals.fullname LIKE '%adam%' AND individuals_dynamics.degree BETWEEN '1' AND '3' AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),individuals.day_of_birth))))+0 BETWEEN '7' AND '10' AND individuals_dynamics.weight BETWEEN  '20' AND '40' AND individuals_dynamics.degree BETWEEN '7' AND '10' AND deleted != 'yes' AND active != 'no' AND recognized = 'yes' 
                  GROUP BY
                    individuals.record_timestamp
```

#### **EDIT 5:**

The desired result would be to have in a final array the key total, that would represent the total amount of results that were extracted in the current query based on dynamic PHP variables, as `$detailed_search_query` and `$display`:

Now I have always 1 in the total. When it should be 75:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [individual_id] => 71
            [1] => 71
            [unique_id] => f598e2ae
            [2] => f598e2ae
            [fullname] => Name2 Name2 Name2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [individual_id] => 65
            [1] => 65
            [unique_id] => b76497ca
            [2] => b76497ca

        )
```

Comment: I wounder what is the result using `COUNT(var)` and `var` in the same select query. Just a little observation!

Comment: Let's me add it to the question

Comment: what happens when you give the count an alias?

Comment: Take a look at my last edit, please!

Comment: I'm staring to have a feeling that I need to have sub-query here, maybe?

Comment: can you add the query after the php variables have been replaced so we can see the whole query

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: And it has to be done ALWAYS with LEFT JOIN on the other table, this is where the problem begins for me.

Comment: How can we count SOMETHING that has to go through the LEFT JOIN first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error that you get means that PDO can't prepare the query, and the reason is that there is an error in your SQL query and the database server can't execute it ... So to let understand better the question you should post the error that you get trying to executing the query on the mysql client directly .

To achieve the result set you need, you can insert a subquery that count the records that have the same `individual_id` as the outer query.

Following the first part of the query :

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(unique_id) FROM individuals i2 WHERE i2.individual_id = individuals. individual_id) AS total,
individuals.individual_id,
individuals.unique_id,
individuals.fullname,
individuals.day_of_birth,
```

Bear in mind that to reference a column of the outer query correctly from the subquery you should use two different alias name, even if you are selecting from the same table in both query (outer and sub).

Comment: Exactly, nice tip!! You have a gap in your example, by the way! This is what I meant! Works as expected! Thanks!

Comment: I was to hasty saying that it works perfectly! It did with simple example, but I need to COUNT on results that have to be LEFT JOIN first. When I build the query it returned same error! Could you  take a look at new edit on my question, please?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Why can't you just count for one column ? e.g : COUNT(
                        individuals.unique_id) . Don't use individuals as alias in the subquery, but use another name, see my example and don't change the meaning of the example when you transfer to your context ...

Comment: because `$detailed_search_query`, `$display` is dynamic! The total depends on PHP variables above that are always different and affect total results

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to make this, I thought simple and plain query work? :)

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev yes, but it doesn't matter if two parts of the query are generated dynamically ... Read again and carefully my updated answer and eventually post the error message of mysql . If you need more help create an SCCE example on sqlfiddle and post the link ...

Comment: I don't understand! Sorry! Your example always return 1? What is **i2**?

Comment: i2 is the alias of the table individuals table in the count subquery. Your implementationis different than mine ... You are comparing the same column because of the same alias name ...

Comment: But if I try to use your example just as you shown it, it also returns 1. Always 1. If I add AS it to your example (here FROM individuals AS i2 ), then same thing happen!

Comment: How can we count SOMETHING that has to go through the LEFT JOIN first?

Comment: Put One colum that came from the joinef table into the Count function

Comment: That column is from the other table that LEFT JOIN hasn't happen to it yet!! To your example I need to add **$detailed_search_query, $display** vars that CONTAIN elements from the other table which I only LEFT JOIN later!!

Comment: I think that there is a misunderstanding here ... Create a working example on SQLfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/), and then we can try to work on a real example .

Comment: I can't post my tables to sqlfiddle. Your answer and explanations are good enough for me! I will work it out! Thanks!